# Error in initializing the YouTube player embedded into app

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to build android app which requires to open YouTube video. I'm using embedded YouTube player to play YouTube video in my application. 
But I'm get the following error:

> An error Occurred While Initializing the YouTube Player
>   What does this error means?

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBx5WtljJM0xq4TRqEsSh-V0ltd0elfOSk";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "B-3e_Ynhwj4";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }
    private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
        }
    };
    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please put some code of what you tried.

Comment: Can you please write more detail about your problem? Also please put some code as suggested by @Michal_196.